use bundles built with eclipse tycho as dependency in simple maven project
I would like to add an simple eclipse tycho bundle as dependency to another maven project.
The tycho bundle builds with mvn clean verify:

This bundle should be added to a separated project as dependency:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.examples.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.examples.tycho.plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

But if added to the project I get an error in eclipse:

Could not find artifact  com.examples.tycho:com.examples.tycho.plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT


I tried adding as module but the error remains:
<module>../tycho-example/com.examples.tycho/bundles/com.examples.tycho.plugin</module>

I tried tycho version 1.2.0 and 4.0.7.
Is it possible to reference a tycho built bundle in another maven project as dependency?
EDIT: I now managed to resolve the build problem using mvn clean install as suggested in the comments (also eclipse restart was required, refresh or maven update did not help).
This now has a major downside, for every code change I would have to run mvn clean install. This does not apply e.g. for a simple maven project, eclipse recognises and applies the changes automatically.
Having a plain maven project with the following declaration:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>separated-maven-project</groupId>
  <artifactId>separated-maven-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>separated-maven-project</name>
</project>

I can add as dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>separated-maven-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>separated-maven-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

I don't have to run mvn clean install and eclipse finds the project and applies/compiles code changes. I'm looking for a similar behvior for the dependency of a tycho based bundle, is there a solution?

verify does not make the artifacts that has been built available in your local Maven repository. Does mvn clean install work instead?

In your separated-maven-project you can add the plugin project as dependency, either in Project > Properties: Java Build Path, tab Projects which would have the disadvantage that it would be overridden by the next Maven > Update Projects, or you add the output folder with the .class files in the POM which would have the disadvantage that the POM will polluted.

This helped, after adding the project the code changes are applied. Thanks.

This is the setup I came up with to reference tycho projects from a separated maven project.
The tycho project itself requires a pom.xml even with the org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-build active in the extensions.xml (pomless).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.examples.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.examples.tycho.bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>com.examples.tycho.plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>

The separated root maven project declares the tycho root project as module:
<modules>
    <module>../tycho-example/com.examples.tycho</module>
</modules>

The maven project which actually uses classes of the tycho project declares the dependency to the tycho bundle:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.examples.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.examples.tycho.plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

This enables building without having to install the tycho bundles in the local repository.
And finally the eclipse project (same in which the maven dependency is declared) adds the tycho project to the classpath, this applies code changes automatically when launching within eclipse.

